# Knowing length of input argument of a function in python

Tags: python, function

Let's say now I have a function:

```
def func(x, p): return p[0] * x ** 2 + p[1] * x + p[2]
```

And now, I can get the information about the function using inspect:

```
import inspect
args, varargs, varkw, defaults = inspect.getargspec(func)
```

But I only know I have two arguments, instead of the information on each argument (whether it's a scalar or something else).

Just making sure - theoretically, is there any way that I can know the minimum length of the tuple p used in the function?

Thank you!

Comment: "is there any way that I can know the minimum length of the tuple p used in the function?". Yes: write it explicitly in the docstring of the function.

Comment: Why is this post tagged with `numpy` and `scipy` tags? If you have something specific in mind you should state that in your question.

Comment: @ViktorKerkez Thanks for noting! I removed those two tags.

Comment: @Bakuriu Thanks! I meant to say "how to get it programmatically" though. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no.

Firstly you can't assume the type (let alone the size of the argument).

Secondly, there is no way to tell the length, because it's supposed to be arbitrary and the function may do nothing about the input at all.

if you do want something similar, try to use *l for variable-length arguments. similarly there is **d for arbitrary map (named arguments).

Comment: Thanks Li! This really helped a lot for me to understand the problem.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot enforce neither the type nor the value of the argument that is passed to your function.

The only thing you can do is annotate your functions in python 3: [annotations](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#function-annotations), But even that doesn't prevent the user from passing in something invalid.

*Note: actually you can enforce by checking directly in the function or with a decorator, but that doesn't help in your case.*

Comment: I see. Thank you Viktor! This is really helpful. I accepted Li's answer because that one helped me understand the issue better; however this one is more helpful in providing ways to work around it. Thanks again!